# Could not find a version that satisfies a requirement ' ' from requirement.txt. No matching distribution found for the package

Tags: python, docker, deployment, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to install some python packages from requirement.txt in my dockerfile.
For every other package, it is throwing the error of 
'Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement from requirement.json
 No matching distributions for it'

Packages include json, csv,re and many more.

I am running it on ubuntu 16.04, and using an image of 'python:3.6-slim'

I found many questions on this, but could not solve my problem.
I have tried updating my pip as well.

Can someone help me with this?

The dockerfile is

```
FROM python:3.6-slim

WORKDIR /app

ADD . . 

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade python-pip -y

RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r req.txt

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["python", "server_reformulator_inference.py"]
```

And requirement.txt is

```
numpy
requests
openpyxl
xlsxwriter
absl-py
google-apputils
grpcio
grpcio-tools
keras
nltk
pandas
portpicker
pygtrie
sentencepiece
tensorflow==1.12.2
tensorflow-tensorboard
spacy
Flask
Flask-Excel
tqdm
argparse
multiprocessing
enum
six
pprint
```

Comment: Which package in `requirement.txt` show your error? I mean `For every other package`, what do this mean, something ok, something not ok?

Comment: yes it shows error for   json
csv
re
random
time
codecs
abc
collections
shutil
tempfile
math
functools
subprocess
logging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json, csv, re` etc. are all build-in modules, you should not install them use `pip`.

See next, they are all in python standard library path `/usr/lib/python3.6`.

```
root@orange:~# python3 -c 'import json; print(json.__file__)'
/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py
root@orange:~# python3 -c 'import csv; print(csv.__file__)'
/usr/lib/python3.6/csv.py
root@orange:~# python3 -c 'import re; print(re.__file__)'
/usr/lib/python3.6/re.py
```

As a compare, see `requests` which is not a build-in module, it lies in `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages`:

```
root@orange:~# python3 -c 'import requests; print(requests.__file__)'
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py
```